# Dynamically add values to List<double> using get & set

Tags: c#, list, properties

Is it possible to do somethink like

```
public class TestClass
{
        public List<double> preTvoltage 
        {
            get 
            {
                return preTvoltage;
            } 
            set 
            { 
                preTvoltage.Add(this); //how to add to the List??
            } 
        }
}
```

The reason I want to do this (I do not know if this is a best method, just as far as my knowledge allows) because I have to get data from xml files that do not have always same number of data in them.

Later I want to fill a ListView rows and using list I can count how many items are and how many columns will be needed.

Here is a schematic of xml file:
[image]
and there are also Trigger and PostTrigger nodes in xml file with same data sorting.
and here is the listview I want to achive:
[image]
[Link to full size image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/programexample.png/)

So, there are some pin groups and each pingroup has lots of data, the above code I gave, was just to hold 1 of the voltage nodes in xml file.

I am pretty much listening for your ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which is your goal? While assigning a new List<double> (that does mean set) you want to add your class (containing list).. Why?

Comment: I am updating the question check back later please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve my problem this way:

```
public class ITestData
{
    public string pinName { get; set; } //Name of the pin
    public double stressLevel { get; set; } //Stress level for latchup
    public int psuCount { get; set;} //Number of PSU's 

    public List<double[]> preTrigger = new List<double[]>();
    public List<double[]> inTrigger = new List<double[]>();
    public List<double[]> postTrigger = new List<double[]>();


    public void AddPreTrigger(double volt, double curr)
    {
        double[] data = new double[2];
        data[0] = volt;
        data[1] = curr;
        preTrigger.Add(data);
    }

    public void AddInTrigger(double volt, double curr)
    {
        double[] data = new double[2];
        data[0] = volt;
        data[1] = curr;
        inTrigger.Add(data);
    }

    public void AddPostTrigger(double volt, double curr)
    {
        double[] data = new double[2];
        data[0] = volt;
        data[1] = curr;
        postTrigger.Add(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of two doubles instead of encapsulating the "voltage, current" pair as a separate type? And please don't have public fields like this...

Comment: @Jon Thanks but I did not got what you mean by encapsulating those two values in separate types?

Comment: Not in separate types - in *one* separate type. So instead of these arrays, you'd have a `Power` type with `Voltage` and `Current` properties.

Answer (score 5):

No, and it defies usage of properties - you should implement it as an `Add` (or similarly aptly named) method.

You can't add `this`, because `this` is a `TestClass`, not a `double`; and you can't add `value`, as [otherwise suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834939/dynamically-add-values-to-listdouble-using-get-set/7834989#7834989), because that is a `List<double>`, and `Add` requires a `double`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear how you would use this, but it looks like a **very bad idea** to me. Setting a collection as a property is *slightly* unusual already, but it's even odder for that set operation to *mutate* the list. It's *additionally* weird that you're not using the `value` variable within the setter... why not?

You should consider what the calling code would look like, and whether that's *really* the clearest way of expressing the semantics you want.

Comment: yeah I agree but that is only limit of my knowledge. I updated the question with what I want to do. have a look please.

Comment: @Sean87: It's still not clear what you want the *code* to look like, and why you'd want to use a property setter for it.

Comment: kind of hard to explain, I want to create a ListView like the one in the question, using the data in that XML schematic. Lets think like this: I only want the pin #J6 to be added into ListView, that will be 3 rows. But Number of columns varies from file to file, so I need to know how many columns should I add befor adding rows. The number of columns should be twice the number of PSUs (that is avilable in XML files) since I need 1 column for voltage and one for Current for each PSU. The first 5 columns are always fixed. Let me know if it is not clear yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sean87: It's *still* not clear what you think the code should look like, or why you'd want to add something in a setter. Write your ideal code to *use* the class, and present that - then work out how to implement it. I doubt that the design you come up with will include a setter like that...

Comment: I managed to solve the problem and recrate the listview. please have a look to the answer I posted here. If you think  there are better ways to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

```
set { preTvoltage.AddRange(value); }
```

As Jon Skeet is saying, this is not what you should do. Instead, do

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
t.PreTvoltage.Add(...);
```

declaring the property as

```
public List<double> PreTvoltage
{
    get { return preTvoltage; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of a getter and setter must match.

You could have:

```
public List<double> preTvoltage 
{
  get 
  {
    return preTvoltage;
  } 
  set 
  { 
    preTvoltage.AddRange(value); //add all items in list assigned.
  } 
}
```

However, this seems like a bad idea as it would be confusing to users why the value got did not match the value just set. I would have the two operations as separate members, and the setter either not exist or else overwrite the existing `preTvoltage` entirely.

Comment: Won't work. You are trying to add a `List<double>` instead of a `double` in a `List<double>`.

Comment: @Otiel, no I'm not. I'm trying to `AddRange` a `List<double>`, which would indeed work. It would likely be a bad idea, or not what they actually want, but I've already noted that.

Comment: You're right, I read too fast and thought `Add` instead of `AddRange`. My mistake.

Comment: @Otiel: No you did not misread the answer. In the first version, it actually said `Add`. That's why I posted my answer using the correct `AddRange`. Jon must have fixed his "bug" at the same time you wrote your comment.

Comment: Did I? I could have fixed it as too obvious an error to even remember fixing, but if so it was too obvious an error for me to even remember fixing... ;)

Comment: @Jon: My English is not good enough to understand that sentence :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can not implement it like this, the preferable way is to make collection controls like:

```
private IList<double> _preTvoltage = new List<double>();

public IEnumerable<double> preTvoltage 
{
    get 
    {
        return preTvoltage.AsEnumerable();
    } 
}

public void AddTvoltage(double item)
{
  _preTvoltage.Add(item);
}
```